# Split polygon parts of a single SpatialPolygons Object

Tags: r, spatial, polygons

In R, I have single `SpatialPolygons` object (i.e. multi-polygons) containing several hundred polygons. I would like to split this `SpatialPolygons` object into a list of `Polygons` (i.e. holes should remain attached to the parent polygon).

Any idea how to do this?

EDITED:

Using the following example provided in the `sp` package:

```
# simple example, from vignette("sp"):
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
```

Then running `out = lapply(SpP@polygons, slot, "Polygons")`. I get a list of three `Polygons` (i.e. `Srs1`, `Srs2`, `Srs3`).

However, the case I am trying to solve is a bit different from this example. The `SpatialPolygons` object I am trying to split is the result of a geometric union done with the `gUnaryUnion` function (in the `RGEOS` package). If I apply `out <- lapply(merged.polygons@polygons, slot, "Polygons")`, I get a unique list of `Polygon` objects (n.b. not a list of `Polygons` objects). In other words, each polygon is separated from its hole(s).

Running  `topol <- sapply(unlist(out), function(x) x@hole)`

I get:

```
> length(topol)
[1] 4996


> sum(topol, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 469
```

According to the `RGEOS` v0.3-2 manual (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/rgeos.pdf):

> In order for rgeos to function properly it is necessary that all holes
>   within a given POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON geometry must belong to a
>   speciﬁc polygon. The SpatialPolygons class implementation does not
>   currently include this information. To work around this limitation
>   rgeos uses an additional comment attribute on the Polygons class that
>   indicates which hole belongs to which polygon. Under the current
>   implementation this comment is a text string of numbers separated by
>   spaces where the order of the numbers corresponds to the order of the
>   Polygon objects in the Polygons slot of the Polygons object. A 0
>   implies the Polygon object is a polygon, a non-zero number implies
>   that the Polygon object is a hole with the value indicating the index
>   of the Polygon that “owns” the hole.

So the `createSPComment()` function in `RGEOS` is likely to be a workaround to reaggregate Polygons and holes.

Answer (score 15):

To separate multipolygon objects into single polygons (with holes if present) you can do

```
d <- disaggregate(p)
```

Where `p` is a `SpatialPolygons` object. After that, you can use `d@polygons`.

For example

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
### example data
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- list(p1, hole)
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0))
p3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0))
pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2, p3)
###

a <- aggregate(pols, dissolve=FALSE)
d <- disaggregate(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the OP wants to convert a `SpatialPolygons` object into a list of `Polygons`, preserving holes if present.

The `SpP` object created by the OP contains three polygons, the third of which has an associated hole.

You can use `lapply` to cycle through each polygon in `SpP`, returning a list of `SpatialPolygons`.  The difference between a `Polygons` and `SpatialPolygons` object is the addition of plot order information.  Since each resulting `SpatialPolygons` is of length = 1, however, this information is superfluous.

```
n_poly <- length(SpP)

out <- lapply(1:n_poly, function(i) SpP[i, ])

lapply(out, class)

> lapply(out, class)
   [[1]]
   [1] "SpatialPolygons"
   attr(,"package")
   [1] "sp"

   [[2]]
   [1] "SpatialPolygons"
   attr(,"package")
   [1] "sp"

   [[3]]
   [1] "SpatialPolygons"
   attr(,"package")
   [1] "sp"

plot(out[[3]]) # Hole preserved
```

If a list of `Polygons` is needed, simply pull the appropriate slot from the `SpatialPolygons` object:

```
out <- lapply(1:n_poly, function(i) SpP[i, ]@polygons[[1]])

lapply(out, class)

> lapply(out, class)
[[1]]
[1] "Polygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

[[2]]
[1] "Polygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

[[3]]
[1] "Polygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `SpatialPolygons` object is called `mysp`...

```
out <- lapply( mysp@polygons , slot , "Polygons" )
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of SpatialPolygons instead of ordinary Polygons (which some of the answers do).

```
SpP %>% split(1:length(.))
```